# Best place to add shadow to view in viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add a shadow (using the layer property of the view) to my view controller's view. Should I do this in load view after creating the view myself.
Or should I do this in ViewDidLoad.

EDIT: Currently I haven't implemented loadView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, if you're using `loadView`, it doesn't really matter whether you configure the shadow there or in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` will be called right after `loadView`, in every case.

The longer version is that if in the future you decided to move your view creation into a XIB file, you would want to remove your implementation of `loadView`. In that case, you would need to customize the layer shadow in `viewDidLoad`. So theoretically you could save your future self some copy and paste work by putting it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: So if I don't already have a loadView method I should use viewDidLoad? This seems to contradict Max's answer?

Comment: Yes, if you are using a XIB then you should use viewDidLoad for this purpose. I disagree with Max's answer, as the customization of subviews has little to do with which of these two methods you do it in.

Answer (score 0):

the loadView method is intended for view controller's view creation. So if you want to add shadow to it, then this would be the best place. And if you want to customize it's subviews, then it's better to do that in viewDidLoad